# Formatting output list

Tags: c, printf

Say, I have a few lines of code that outputs a list of some admins(random scenario) and they go like this

```
printf("ADMIN LISTT\n\n");
printf("FIRSTNAME        LASTNAME        PASSWORD       AGE       ACOUNT#\n");
printf("\n%s          %s           %s    %d     %d\n",
students.firstname, students.lastname, students.password,
students.age_calculation, students.account_num);
```

the output would be very ugly like this

```
FIRSTNAME        LASTNAME        PASSWORD       AGE \n");
SAM       WITHER               SAMWITHER123  25     
TEBBY             BOWSER           GIRZZLY145    18
```

Each field isn't correctly displayed under its right topic is there a way to make them better I don't think there's a way to make them precisely under the topics because they are placed there from user input and as each character is entered the spacing pushes the others further to the right and that cause the problem(the positions on the screen are all based on the amount of characters entered by the user)

Answer (score 3):

use like by assuming that student name,last name,password would be upto 40 char. and age and accuont num upto 3 digit.

```
printf("\n%-40s %-40s %-40s %-3s %-3s\n","FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME","PASSWORD","AGE","ACOUNT");

printf("\n%-40s %-40s %-40s %-3d %-3d\n",students.firstname, students.lastname,students.password, students.age_calculation, students.account_num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this ...

```
printf("%14s%14s%14s%5s%8s\n", 
"FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "PASSWORD", "AGE", "ACOUNT#");

printf("%14s%14s%14s%5d%8d\n",
students.firstname, students.lastname, students.password,
students.age_calculation, students.account_num);
```

Comment: @user3293168 glad to worked it.now accept the answer